# Which is faster in java charAt() or startsWith()?

Tags: java, performance

My question is, if I want to check a character (only one character to check) of a string in a particular index which method is very efficient `charAt()` or `startsWith()`. I mean in comparison of time complexity as far I can guess `startsWith()` gets more time than `charAt()`. Because `startsWith()` needs to check a set of characters, but `charAt()` just need to check only one character.

Now tell me your opinion… what you think about which is efficient to use to check only one character?

Comment: charAt() and StartsWith() are two different function 1st one will return you the character at particular position in string and 2nd checks if String starts with particular string or not. So you cant use startsWith () to check a character of a string at particular index

Comment: Please note that you can still accept an answer. And I disagree that the question got put on hold for being opinionatd.

Answer (score 4):

Both methods can be used to check a specific character for its value.

`charAt()` directly returns the char at the requested index, `startsWith(prefix, index)` will return true if you provide corresponding arguments.

The major difference is that the second approach has a bit more of overhead.

So, theoretically option 1 has slightly better performance. But beyond that, you rather pick option 1 because that just does what you want in the most clear way.

The really important difference is not about performance, but about your code communicating your *intent*. So, albeit is possible to use `startsWith()` to do what you want, it is simply counterintuitive to use it that way.

Answer (score 2):

*if I want to check a character(Only one character to check) of a string in a particular index*

You answered by yourself. If you need to check that in a **particular index**, you can't use `startsWith()` , because you can't choose the index.

They do different jobs, so , based on your question, always use `charAt()`

Comment: Wrong. There is a 2nd less known version of that starts with that takes an offset. But I had to look that up my self, too.