# In JavaScript, what's the most performant way to determine the first character in a string: startsWith, charAt, or [0]

Tags: javascript

While writing some code that needs to be as performant as possible, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519358/which-is-faster-in-java-charat-or-startswith) question about `charAt` vs `startsWith`, but then realized it applied specifically to Java. After running some tests on jsperf.com, I found my answer. See below.

Comment: `startsWith` can't be used to get the first character of a string?!

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, that's correct. `charAt` and `[0]` will return the first character in a string; `startsWith` returns a boolean value. You can read more about its behavior [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith). Each of these methods will allow you to *determine* if the first character of a string matches a specific character.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant with "determine".

Comment: Do you think another word choice would make this meaning more obvious? I'd hate to make the title longer, but I suppose we could update the question with a more verbose explanation, if you think it would increase the clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## UPDATED — 2023 Dec 11

#### tl;dr — On your marks...

It's a tight race between `.startsWith` and `[0]`, with `.startsWith` taking the lead. `.charAt` is in a distant third place, with `.match` falling woefully behind.

Tested on:

- Google Chrome Version 120.0.6099.71 (Official Build) (arm64)
- Apple M1 Pro (2021)
- macOS 14.2 Beta (23C5041e)

### [JSBench.me Results](https://jsbench.me/welq15149d/1)

***Setup Code***

```
const strs = [
  '',
  '*',
  '#',
  '*short',
  '#short',
  '*'.padEnd(2500, '-'),
  '#'.padEnd(2500, '-'),
]
```

***.startsWith***

```
strs.forEach(str => str.startsWith('*'))
// 75M ops/s ± 9.34%
// Fastest
```

***.charAt***

```
strs.forEach(str => str.charAt(0) === '*')
// 23M ops/s ± 2.13%
// 69.7 % slower
```

***[0]***

```
strs.forEach(str => str[0] === '*')
// 69M ops/s ± 4.45%
// Fastest
```

***.match***

```
strs.forEach(str => str.match(/^\*/))
// 5.3M ops/s ± 1.77%
// 92.89 % slower
```

***NOTE:*** I've run this benchmark a few times and `[0]` occasionally wins, but these stats are representative of the typical results I got.

Comment: https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html

Comment: Interesting. I guess `startsWith` is the fastest because it doesn't have to create and return a 1 character long string.

Comment: I just want to highlight how inconsequential the measured difference is.  Granted you'd still choose startsWith, just because it looks nicer, but the performance is negligible and you aren't really even measuring the operation's difference anymore: https://jsperf.com/trevors-startswith-vs-charat/5  which, I guess you've already pointed out sort of in your comment and link up there

Comment: @user120242 That's a good point, it is negligible in a lot of use cases. I think though there are use cases where if you needed to make this determination on a significant amount of data it adds up to be a big performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing and was futzing around on codepen with mixed results. I went to your [test](https://perf.link/#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%2BIHN0ci5zdGFydHNXaXRoKCcqJykpIiwicnVucyI6WzQzMTAwMCwzMDAwMCw2NTIwMDAsMTE5MzAwMCw3NzMwMDAsNDcwMDAwLDU4ODAwMCw4MDgwMDAsNTI2MDAwLDQ1MDAwLDIwMDAwMCwxMDc1MDAwLDU5MDAwLDEzNDIwMDAsMTA3MDAwMCw5NzMwMDAsNTE1MDAwLDk2NTAwMCw3MTcwMDAsMTQ3NzAwMCw5MjkwMDAsMTA4MDAwLDEwMDAsMTUxMDAwLDQxNjAwMCwyNjEwMDAsMTQ5ODAwMCwxMjAwMDAwLDY1MjAwMCwxMzgxMDAwLDEyNTAwMCwzODIwMDAsNzQyMDAwLDQwMTAwMCw5OTMwMDAsOTYyMDAwLDUyMzAwMCwxMDg4MDAwLDczMDAwLDEyMzAwMCwxMzYxMDAwLDgwOTAwMCwxNTAwMCwxMjQ2MDAwLDkxMzAwMCw4MTQwMDAsMTM4MTAwMCwxOTIwMDAsNzgxMDAwLDE0OTAwMDAsNTM2MDAwLDEzODEwMDAsNjI1MDAwLDEwODYwMDAsMjI4MDAwLDEzNTMwMDAsMTI1OTAwMCw3MDAwMCwxNDc1MDAwLDUwNzAwMCwxNDg2MDAwLDk4MDAwLDIyNDAwMCwxMzgxMDAwLDU5MzAwMCw5MzkwMDAsNTI5MDAwLDg2NzAwMCwzNDkwMDAsNTUyMDAwLDE0MTAwMDAsNTAwMDAsNzExMDAwLDE3NTAwMCw2ODkwMDAsNTAwMDAsNjQxMDAwLDM1MDAwMCw1MzcwMDAsMTM4MTAwMCwxMjY2MDAwLDc1NzAwMCwxOTYwMDAsMjI4MDAwLDkwMzAwMCwyMDAwLDEwMjAwMDAsMzg2MDAwLDQzMTAwMCwxMDAwLDM2NjAwMCw5ODcwMDAsMTEzMTAwMCwxMzI2MDAwLDcyMDAwMCwyNTkwMDAsOTUyMDAwLDMyNDAwMCwxMjU5MDAwLDEzNzgwMDBdLCJvcHMiOjcwMzQ0MH0seyJuYW1lIjoiY2hhckF0IiwiY29kZSI6InN0cnMuZm9yRWFjaChzdHIgPT4gc3RyLmNoYXJBdCgwKSA9PT0gJyonKSIsInJ1bnMiOls2MTkwMDAsMzQwMDAsMTAxODAwMCw4MDEwMDAsNTYyMDAwLDY0NzAwMCw4NTUwMDAsMTI0MjAwMCw4NDkwMDAsMzAyMDAwLDE5MTAwMCw5ODYwMDAsMTAxODAwMCwyMDAwLDIwMTAwMCw3ODUwMDAsNzU2MDAwLDEyMDAwLDEzNDAwMCw1NjAwMCw4NzIwMDAsNzAwMDAwLDMxMzAwMCw4NDAwMDAsMTAwMCwxMjIyMDAwLDEwNDEwMDAsMCw0NTEwMDAsNTAyMDAwLDEwMTgwMDAsOTIyMDAwLDc5NjAwMCw4NjAwMCw3NzUwMDAsMTMwMDAsOTA0MDAwLDEyODAwMDAsMTQ3MDAwLDY0OTAwMCw3MjIwMDAsMTAxODAwMCw2NjAwMCw0MjMwMDAsNDczMDAwLDU5MzAwMCwxMjcwMDAsODIzMDAwLDE5MjAwMCwxMTU0MDAwLDQwNzAwMCw2MjcwMDAsMTQzMjAwMCw5MjQwMDAsMjAyMDAwLDU4NzAwMCwxMjEyMDAwLDIwNzAwMCwxMzQyMDAwLDY2MjAwMCwxMTc0MDAwLDg0OTAwMCw3MzAwMCwzODEwMDAsMTE2NDAwMCwxMjIwMDAwLDEyNjgwMDAsNTk0MDAwLDExOTUwMDAsOTAyMDAwLDEzNDkwMDAsNTk5MDAwLDU1NTAwMCw0NDAwMDAsMjAwMCw1OTAwMDAsMTAwMCw4OTIwMDAsODQ0MDAwLDE2MDAwMCwzNjQwMDAsNTAyMDAwLDExMjMwMDAsMTAxNzAwMCw0NzYwMDAsMTE0ODAwMCw2ODEwMDAsMjY2MDAwLDExOTkwMDAsMTAxODAwMCwxMDE4MDAwLDk1MjAwMCwxMzQ4MDAwLDExMTMwMDAsMzM3MDAwLDIwMDAsMTA0MDAwLDEzMDAwMDAsNTMzMDAwLDE5MDAwXSwib3BzIjo2NTU2NzB9LHsibmFtZSI6IlswXSIsImNvZGUiOiJzdHJzLmZvckVhY2goc3RyID0%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%3D) and added a case for `str.match(/^\*/)`. It won by a longshot.

Comment: I think maybe you didn't realize it's measuring it in operations per second.  The `str.match(/^\*/)` shown at your provided link is unsurprisingly the slowest of the bunch.